# Django Channel - Nginx cannot connect to websocket

Tags: django, nginx, websocket

I've been stuck for days just to find a way to fix this problem.

Why my Nginx can't connect to WebSocket? and always get these errors on the console:

```
WebSocket connection to '<URL>' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

or

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://domain.com/virtualexpo/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

Here's my Nginx setup looks like:

```
upstream projectname {
        server localhost:9001;
}

upstream uvsock {
        server 127.0.0.1:6379;
        # server unix://var/run/supervisor.sock;
}
server {
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
        sendfile on;
        charset utf-8;
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        client_body_buffer_size 80M;
        client_body_timeout 50;
        location /ws/ {
                proxy_pass http://uvsock;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://projectname;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_redirect off;
                ...

        }
        location /static {
                alias /home/username/server/vier/staticfiles;
        }
        location /media {
                alias /home/username/server/vier/media;
        }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = www.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    if ($host = domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
        listen 80;
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

How can I connect this Nginx with my WebSocket for use with Django Channel?

Here's my `routing.py` looks like:

```py
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # "http": get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                [
                    path('stream/<pk>/', LiveStreamConsumer),
                    path('discussion/global/', GlobalLiveChatConsumer),
                    path('somepath/', VirtualExpoConsumer)
                ]
            )
        )
    )
})
```

The ASGI setup:

```py
...
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer


from channels.routing import get_default_application

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'core.settings'

django.setup()
channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
application = get_default_application()
# application = get_asgi_application()
```

And my `settings.py` looks like this:

```py
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("localhost", 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

Been around looking for a way to fix them but can't find any.

The celery and Redis themselves have already run with no issue.
But it seems that the WebSocket can't connect with my Nginx config.

Answer (score 0):

This is might due to your daphne server wasn't able to access the cert to redirect to wss. You may refer article [here](https://github.com/mitchtabian/HOWTO-django-channels-daphne).